# chained select with Cakephp and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Hello i'm using CakePhp i'm trying to make a chained select with Ajax, 
the idea is that i make the jQuery action in the event onchange of the select input

```
onchange="TheFunction()";
```

but it seems like i have some syntax problém, the idea is that i send the value of the selected item to the function ShowProvider that searches for the providers that belongs to the selected category, and then sends it back to the callback function.

echo $this->Form->input('category_id',array('empty'=>'Selectionnez une','options'=>$categories,'class'=>'category','onchange'=>'

```
    <?php
            echo "

            $.get(
            //premier argument, le lien vers lequel on envoie les données
            '. $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'articles','actions'=>'ShowProvider'),true) .',
            //2eme argument, on envoie l\'id de la catégorie selectionné
            {id:$("select.category option:selected").attr("value")},

            3éme argument   
            function(data){
                alert("wssel");
            }
            )
            "
        ?>
    '));
```

here is the action ShowProcider()

```
public function ShowProvider(){
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $result = $this->Article->Provider->find('list',
            array('conditions'=>
                    array('category_id'=>$this->request->query['id'])
            )
        );
        if ($result) {
            $ret['name']=$result['Provider']['name'];
        }
        else{
            $ret['name']='Vide.';
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Thank's in Advance :)

Comment: That looks like little bit "self-build". Using the frameworks JsonView you could make this a lot cleaner. Also see http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/ There is also a live example on exactly that.

Comment: thank's for teh help man i will try it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/taleeb35/66abaae65ccd2d01a2c1

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
$this->autoRender = false;
```

juste before

```
public function ShowProvider(){
```

and remove

```
exit();
```